# PySimpleGUi: Unable to complete operation on element with key 0

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm creating a program that asks the user to guess a certain number that the computer will draw. In the tutorial I'm following to make this program, the tutor uses PySimplesGUI to create an interactive window. This is the program code:

```
import random
import PySimpleGUI as sg

class GessNumberSimulator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.randon_value = 0
        self.min_value = 1
        self.max_value = 60
        self.number_chances = 10

    def Start(self):
        layout = [
            [sg.Text('Your guess',size=(20,0))],
            [sg.Input(size=(18,0),key='GuessValue')],
            [sg.Button('Guess!')],
            [sg.Output(size=(20,10))]
        ]
        # create a window
        self.window = sg.Window('Guess Number Simulator', layout=layout)
        

        self.GenerateNumber()
        self.RequestNumber()
        try:
            while True:
                # receive the values
                self.event, self.values = self.window.Read()
                self.guess_value = self.values['GuessValue']
            if self.event == 'Guess!':
                while self.number_chances != 0:
                    if int(self.guess_value) > self.randon_value:
                        print(f'\033[1;32mA little less! (Number of chances: {self.number_chances})\033[m')
                        self.number_chances -= 1
                        self.RequestNumber()
                    elif int(self.guess_value) < self.randon_value:
                        print(f'\033[1;31mA little more! (Number of chances: {self.number_chances})\033[m')
                        self.number_chances -= 1
                        self.RequestNumber()
                    if int(self.guess_value) == self.randon_value:
                        self.try_again = False
                        print(f'\033[1;34m CONGRATULATIONS! The number chosen is {self.randon_value}! You ´ re right! \033[m')
                        break
                    if self.number_chances == 0:
                        print(f'\033[1;35m What a shame! Your chances is over! This number chosen was {self.randon_value}! More luck in the next time!\033[m')
        except:
            print('\033[1;031mPlease insert only integers numbers!\033[m')

    def RequestNumber(self):
        self.guess_value = input('Guess any number: ')
    
    def GenerateNumber(self):
        self.randon_value = random.randint(self.min_value, self.max_value)
        

Guess1 = GessNumberSimulator()
Guess1.Start()
```

When I try to run the program, a PySimpleGUI window pops up with this message:

> Unable to complete operation on element with key 0. You cannot perform (such as calling update) on an Element until window.read() is called or finalize=True when Window created. Adding a "finalize=True" parameter to your Window creation will likely fix this.

[This is a print of the error message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKW48.png)

I tried to check which key the problem was talking about. I tried changing the value of `key='GuessValue'` to 1 thinking this was the key cited by the error message, but the same message came up. I expected to see the PySimplesGUI interactive window working, but to no avail. The program is running fine in the terminal, but the interactive window doesn't even appear when I try to use the PySimplesGUI in the source code. I tried putting `finalize=True"` in both  `self.window = sg.Window('Guess Number Simulator', layout=layout, finalize=True)` and `self.event , self.values ​​= self.window.Read(finalize=True)`, but the PySimpleGUI window doesn't show anything anymore, it goes blank and doesn't work.

Comment: The `Output` element is trying to be used before the window is fully formed.  You're getting an error somewhere else.  Because the Output element has rerouted stdout/stderr that error is causing errors in your GUI.    Remove the Output element until you figure out that error.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't find the exception for your code. To work with a GUI, you should not use console input or output at the same time.

Revised code

```py
import random
import PySimpleGUI as sg

class GessNumberSimulator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.randon_value = 0
        self.min_value = 1
        self.max_value = 60
        self.number_chances = 10

    def Start(self):
        layout = [
            [sg.Text('Your guess'), sg.Input(size=5, key='GuessValue'), sg.Button('Guess!', bind_return_key=True)],
            [sg.Output(size=(80, 10))]
        ]
        self.window = sg.Window('Guess Number Simulator', layout=layout)
        self.GenerateNumber()

        while True:

            event, values = self.window.read()

            if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
                break

            elif event == "Guess!":
                self.window['GuessValue'].update(select=True)
                entry = values['GuessValue']
                if not entry.isdigit():
                    print(f"Worng Number, range from {self.min_value} to {self.max_value} !")
                    continue
                try:
                    guess_value = int(entry)
                except ValueError:
                    print(f"Worng Number, range from {self.min_value} to {self.max_value} !")
                    continue
                if self.number_chances != 0:
                    if guess_value > self.randon_value:
                        print(f'A little less! (Number of chances: {self.number_chances})')
                        self.number_chances -= 1
                    elif guess_value < self.randon_value:
                        print(f'A little more! (Number of chances: {self.number_chances})')
                        self.number_chances -= 1
                    elif guess_value == self.randon_value:
                        sg.popup(f' CONGRATULATIONS! The number chosen is {self.randon_value}! You ´ re right! ')
                        break
                    if self.number_chances == 0:
                        sg.popup(f' What a shame! Your chances is over! This number chosen was {self.randon_value}! More luck in the next time!')
                        break
        self.window.close()

    def GenerateNumber(self):
        self.randon_value = random.randint(self.min_value, self.max_value)


Guess1 = GessNumberSimulator()
Guess1.Start()
```